# Staff-WSF Axis2C SOAP load service component on startup

Tags: web-services, axis2c, staff-wsf

*Impl.h file of a service component has these functions:

```
virtual void OnCreate();
virtual void OnDestroy();
```

OnCreate is called only when the client makes a call to the service.

I'd like to have it when the server `axis2_http_server` is launched. (just one instance of my class that receives OnCreate when the whole server is started and OnDestroy when it is stopped)

Staff-WSF service has loadServiceAtStartup by default, but how to make it load my service components too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a service at server startup you must add `loadAtStartup` metacomment before service class declaration like this:

```
// *loadAtStartup: true
class MyService: public staff::IService
{
```

Please see [this example](https://github.com/loentar/staff/blob/master/staff/samples/calc/component/src/CalcService.h#L32) for full header code.